# Remaping Ctrl+Capslock and Alt+Capslock on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, remapping

I'm trying to disable Capslock and make the following remaps:

```
Ctrl+Capslock => Capslock
Alt+Capslock => Escape (since my Escape key is broken)
```

Right now I'm trying to use Xmodmap.

I have only the following:

```
keycode 66 = NoSymbol Caps_Lock
```

This disables Capslock and maps Shift+Capslock to Capslock, but what I want is Ctrl+Capslock instead of Shift+Capslock.

I have no idea how to map Alt+Capslock to the Escape key.

I want to clarify that I don't need an answer to use Xmodmap, any method will be fine.

Comment: +1 All my life being frustrated how easy it is to press accidentally CAPS while typing fast only to a sentence later discover that you have to retype everything anew.

Comment: Its worse for me, I use vim. Oh the horror! <=O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xmodmap cannot do what you're asking for, but it can bring you close.

The basic syntax for modifying the behavior of a key is

```
xmodmap -e "keycode  KEYCODE = KEYSYMBOL1 KEYSYMBOL1 KEYSYMBOL3 KEYSYMBOL4"
xmodmap -e "keysym KEYSYMBOL = KEYSYMBOL1 KEYSYMBOL1 KEYSYMBOL3 KEYSYMBOL4"
```

where

- `KEYSYMBOL2` gets triggered when pressing the key while pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>.
- `KEYSYMBOL3` gets triggered when pressing the key while pressing <kbd>ModeSwitch</kbd>.
- `KEYSYMBOL4` gets triggered when pressing the key while pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>ModeSwitch</kbd>.
- `KEYSYMBOL1` gets triggered when pressing the key with none of the above.
- <kbd>ModeSwitch</kbd> is <kbd>AltGr</kbd> by default (only works on some keyboard layouts).

We can't set <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> to be the <kbd>ModeSwitch</kbd> key, since no key can serve as two different modifiers.

However, we *can* turn <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> into the <kbd>ModeSwitch</kbd> key:

```
xmodmap -e "keysym Caps_Lock = Mode_switch Mode_switch"
```

To remap <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key, execute the following commands.

```
xmodmap -e "keysym Control_L = Control_L Control_L Caps_Lock"
xmodmap -e "keysym Control_R = Control_R Control_R Caps_Lock"
```

Note the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> is the modifier key here, so you have to press this key first.

We *can't* remap <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> to <kbd>Escape</kbd> in the same manner, since <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd> serve different functions when pressed alone and when used as modifier keys.

Every other key will work fine. Examples:

- For <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> (standard US layout), use

  ```
  xmodmap -e "keysym grave = grave asciitilde Escape"
  ```
- For <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, use

  ```
  xmodmap -e "keysym space = KP_Space KP_Space Escape"
  ```

Tips:

- To make the remappings permanent, create/edit the file `.gnomerc` in your home folder and save the corresponding commands in it.
- To undo all remappings, simply execute

  ```
  setxkbmap
  ```